# attempt to call field 'pullEvent' (a nil value)

Tags: lua

I am getting the following error in my lua code :-
**attempt to call field 'pullEvent' (a nil value)**

The code is as follows:

```
 while true do
  print("Press E to do something.")

  local event, key ,x ,y= os.pullEvent("char") -- limit os.pullEvent to the 'key' event

  if key == keys.e then -- if the key pressed was 'e'
  print("You pressed E. Exiting program...")
  break
 end
end
```

How do i resolve it?

Comment: The error message indicates that there is no `os.pullEvent` function, and in fact Lua's standard library doesn't include such a function. Where is it supposed to come from?

Comment: @siffiejoe could you tell me a way to implement a key press trigger in lua.

Comment: This is going to be platform specific. If you are lucky, there already are C modules like [luaposix](https://github.com/luaposix/luaposix) (also see this [thread](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2013-11/msg00937.html)) or [lua-evdev](https://github.com/Tangent128/lua-evdev) available for your OS to help you. If not, you will have to use another programming language (probably C in combination with OS-specific APIs).

Comment: It comes from Computercraft @siffiejoe.